# Why the "_path" route helper returns string not marked as html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The "_path" route helper returns string not marked as html_safe.

I don't know for sure - maybe it's indeed not html safe, but when I pass something like `"foo>bar"` to _path helper it generates string like:

```
/aa/foo%3Ebar/bb
```

Which looks safe.

However, html_safe? for that string is `false` and if I pass it to template, expectedly I've got:

```
&#47;aa&#47;foo%3Ebar&#47;bb
```

Which looks not so nice.

I can call `.html_safe` on helper output, but maybe there are some cases when _path helpers emit unsafe characters?

Anyway, I don't like the idea to call `html_safe` on every helper output, and hope that framework take care of that stuff.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

This is quit usefull becaus the client may pass variables to the url and if the path would be marked as html_safe for deafult he could simply write some javascript/html/... to the url and it would be executed. That is called a Cross Site Scripting and one of the most "popular" security holes. Of cause its "only" a client side attack but it might get dangerous for your users so its better to not change this by default!

Comment: would you please try to pass, for example ``>`` to _path helper and see what it returns?